# How to prove that one problem belongs to class P?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics, complexity-classes

Is there any formal method to prove that one problem belongs to Complexity Class $\mathbb{P}$?

For example, how can we prove that the problem of finding $n^k$ belongs to Class $\mathbb{P}$? We can use the fact that each multiplication can be done in unit time.

If you present an algorithm that can solve this problem with $\mathcal{O} (\log n)$ time, can it be a proof?

Comment: It's enough to describe an algorithm that solves any given size-$n$ instance of the problem in $O(n^a)$ time for some constant $a$ independent of $n$. It's important to be clear about the machine model (which says what operations are possible and what time they are considered to take, and whether the size $n$ refers to bits or some larger unit) and what information is part of input to the problem (in your example, $k$ could be considered either part of the input, or a fixed part of the problem).

Comment: $\log n=O(n)$ and $n$ is indeed a polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In fact, any algorithm that runs in polynomial time counts. For examle, even an $O(n^8)$ would suffice! Therefore, there is no real need to optimize your algorithms to such extremes.